# Qt set common background for all dialog boxes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am working on developing a Qt 5 widgets desktop application where I want to give a common background for all windows and dialog boxes that pop up. The problem is that for each window I have to specify the same piece of code over and over again to load the same background. I am also using `paint` function override so as not to distort the background when window is resized. Here's my code:

```
SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pixmapBg.load(":/images/google-material-design-wallpaper-10.jpg");
}
void SettingsDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{
        QPixmap pixmapBgL = pixmapBg.scaled(this->size());
        QPalette palette;
        palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, pixmapBgL);
        this->setPalette(palette);
}
```

Is there a way to accommodate this in Qt using a single file rather than mentioning it for each window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! You will have to provide your [own stylesheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html), or initialize your application by calling [QApplication::setStyleSheet(styleName)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop).

Follow up from comment: `setStyleSheet` is the quickest approach, i.e.

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QDialog, QMessageBox {background-image: url(:/images/google-material-design-wallpaper-10.jpg);}");
```

assuming you have a valid QApplication reference `qApp`. Note that you can also refer to your custom subclasses as well, if you want to refine the scope of the stylesheet.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some code? I want the same functionality as the code in my question.

Comment: will this also be able to handle resizing of window?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal the styling follow CSS rules: you can play with any of the `background-*` properties (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) to make the image behave as you intend to.

Comment: I tried this: 
`a.setStyleSheet("QDialog, QMessageBox {background-image: url(:/images/google-material-design-wallpaper-10.jpg); background-size: cover;}");` it keeps giving error: `Unknown property background-size`. The same works when I give it in the .ui editor window

Comment: Ah darn, Qt5 still accepts only CSS2 (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sltylesheet-syntax.htm, sadly still no CSS3) properties... you'll have to play with the ones available here  http://www.mhric.org/pat/css_properties.html

Comment: but how does it (`background-size` ) work when applying via form editor. The style sheet is valid according to Qt. I am using Qt 5.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code using QApplication::setStyleSheet:

```
QString styleSheet = "QWidget{\
                              background-color: yellow\
                             }"//style sheet in CSS style

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);//will set all the QWidgets' background color to yellow
    return app.exec();
}
```

There is actually a background-image property but I'm not sure about which widgets are supporting it so you can check right [there](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).